# How to bind to a MenuItems Property from Control to another MenuItem in Parent View?

Tags: c#, wpf

I got the following View of type MyCustomView:

```
<Grid>
...
<usercontrols:MyUsercontrol>
   <usercontrols:MyUsercontrol.ContextMenu>
       <ContextMenu>
           <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
               <CompositeCollection>
                    <MenuItem IsEnabled="{Binding HOW_TO_BIND_TO_miTest}" Header="Test" Click="DoSomeAction" />
               </CompositeCollection>
           </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
        </ContextMenu>
   </usercontrols:MyUsercontrol.ContextMenu>
 </usercontrols:MyUsercontrol>

...

<Button Style="{StaticResource SidebarButton}" Click="OpenContextMenu" Content="Open Menu">
   <Button.ContextMenu>
      <ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
              <CompositeCollection>
                 <MenuItem x:Name="miTest" Header="Add Account" Click="DoSomeAction"/>
              </CompositeCollection>
           </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
       </ContextMenu>
   </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>

...
</Grid>
```

In the Code-Behind of the View I set the IsEnabled-Property of MenuItem "miTest" to false, so the MenuItem is disabled. How do I synchronise this with the IsEnabled-Property of the embedded UserControls' Contextmenu-Item? I already tried this one:

```
<MenuItem IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Test_binding.IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MyCustomView}}}" Header="Test" Click="DoSomeAction" />
```

and added this Code-Behind:

```
    public MenuItem Test_binding
    {
        get { return this.miTest; }
    }
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a bool Property in your UserControl, Bind it to both of the `MenuItem` in `TwoWay`.. it will be Synchronised.

```
public bool IsEnabled
{
    get { return isEnabled; }
    set { 
             isEnabled = value;
             PropertyChagned("IsEnabled");
        }
}
```

Make sure the UserControl is derived with `INotifyPropertyChagned`...

Bind this property with both `MenuItem`...

```
<MenuItem IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, Mode=Twoway, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MyCustomView}}}" Header="Test" Click="DoSomeAction" />
```